# How to display blob value using x'abc' binary string literal syntax?

Tags: sqlite

You can easily enter a blob value using the x'abc' syntax, but is there a way to display it that way too? As shown below, selecting directly, or implicitly converting to a string using concatenation doesn't work, and shows garbage (Windows DOS prompt here).

```
sqlite> create table blobs (uid blob);
sqlite> insert into blobs values (x'0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef');
sqlite> select * from blobs;
☺#Egë½═∩☺#Egë½═∩
sqlite> select ''||uid from blobs;
☺#Egë½═∩☺#Egë½═∩
```

I'd like the select to display:

```
x'0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef'
```

Thanks, --DD

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
select quote(uid) from blobs
```

returns:

```
X'0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF'
```

and if you really need it in lowercase, you can use:

```
select lower(quote(uid)) from blobs
```

Comment: sqlite3 doesn't work: `select quote(uid) from test;
quote(id)
'☺#Egë½═∩☺#Egë½═∩'`