# Is it possible to (emulate?) AUTOINCREMENT on a compound-PK in Sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, auto-increment, compound-key

According to the SQLite [docs](http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html), the only way to get an auto-increment column is on the primary key.

I need a compound primary key, but I also need auto-incrementing.  Is there a way to achieve both of these in SQLite?

Relevant portion of my table as I would write it in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE tstage (
    id                   SERIAL NOT NULL,
    node                 INT REFERENCES nodes(id) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id,node),
    -- ... other columns
);
```

The reason for this requirement is that all nodes eventually dump their data to a single centralized node where, with a single-column PK, there would be collisions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is correct.
However, it is possible to reimplement the autoincrement logic in a trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE tstage (
    id    INT,  -- allow NULL to be handled by the trigger
    node  INT REFERENCES nodes(id) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, node)
);

CREATE TABLE tstage_sequence (
    seq INTEGER NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO tstage_sequence VALUES(0);

CREATE TRIGGER tstage_id_autoinc
AFTER INSERT ON tstage
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NEW.id IS NULL
BEGIN
    UPDATE tstage_sequence
    SET seq = seq + 1;

    UPDATE tstage
    SET id = (SELECT seq
              FROM tstage_sequence)
    WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid;
END;
```

(Or use a common `my_sequence` table with the table name if there are multiple tables.)

Comment: `SELECT max(id) FROM t` is very efficient if there is an index.

Comment: Does a trigger imply a transaction, or do I need to explicitly begin a transaction before the `UPDATE tstage_sequence...` to guard against races between clients?

Comment: Triggers always run in the same transaction as the triggering command.

Comment: I guess my question was more whether the trigger itself would be atomic. If there is a race, the `UPDATE tstage_sequence` could fire twice, then the `UPDATE tstage` would fail with a unique key violation on the second client. I was hoping for a way to make the trigger atomic, so I don't have to check for this failure in my client code.

Comment: SQLite transactions are always perfectly serialized (because there is no concurrency).

Comment: Which would only help if I'm willing to start a transaction before inserting anything to the 'tstage' table, right?

Comment: When you don't use explicit transactions, SQLite will create an automatic transaction for each single command, but commands in triggers will be included in that transaction.

Comment: Ah very good. That was my question when I asked "Does a trigger imply a transaction?"

Comment: @CL. i want to know that what is `rowid` in the 2nd last line of your code?

Answer (score 1):

A trigger works, but is complex. More simply, you could avoid serial ids. One approach, you could use a [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier). Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to have SQLite generate the GUID for you by default, so you'd have to generate it in your application. There also isn't a GUID type, but you could store it as a string or [a binary blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815587/using-guid-in-sqlite-select-where-guid-is-stored-in-the-sqlite-db-as-binaries).

Or, perhaps there is something in your other columns that would serve as a suitable key. If you know that inserts won't happen more frequently than the resolution of your timestamp format of choice ([SQLite offers several, see section 1.2](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)), then maybe `(node, timestamp_column)` is a good primary key.

Or, you could use SQLite's `AUTOINCREMENT`, but [set the starting number on each node](http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) via the `sqlite_sequence` table such that the generated serials won't collide. Since `rowid` is SQLite is a 64-bit number, you could do this by generating a unique 32-bit number for each node (IP addresses are a convenient, probably unique 32 bit number) and shifting it left 32 bits, or equivalently, multiplying it by 4294967296. Thus, the 64-bit `rowid` becomes effectively two concatenated 32-bit numbers, `NODE_ID, RECORD_ID`, guaranteed to not collide unless one node generates over four billion records.

Comment: `(node,id)` is essentially a GUID already. I see what you're saying though--combine them into a single db field, using a bitmap of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

How about...

ASSUMPTIONS

- Only need uniqueness in PK, not sequential-ness
- Source table has a PK

Create the central table with one extra column, the node number...

```
CREATE TABLE tstage (
    node  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    id    INTEGER NOT NULL,   <<< or whatever the source table PK is
    PRIMARY KEY (node, id)
       :
);
```

When you rollup the data into the centralized node, insert the number of the source node into 'node' and set 'id' to the source table's PRIMARY KEY column value...

```
INSERT INTO tstage (nodenumber, sourcetable_id, ...);
```

There's no need to maintain another autoincrementing column on the central table because nodenumber+sourcetable_id will always be unique.