# Query SQLite database for a GUID in the form X'3D98F71F3CD9415BA978C010b1CEF941

Tags: ios, sql, database, sqlite, rowid

I have an iOS project and data is written into an SQLite Database.  For example, `'OBJECTROWID'` in a table `LDOCLINK` stores info about a linked document.

`OBJECTROWID` starts of as a string with the format `<3d98f71f 3cd9415b a978c010 b1cef941>` but is cast to `(NSData *)` before being input into the database.  The actual handling of the database insertion was written by a much more experienced programmer than myself.  Anyway, as the image below shows, the database displays the `OBJECTROWID` column in the form `X'3D98F71F3CD9415BA978C010b1CEF941'`.  I am a complete beginner with SQLite queries and cannot seem to return the correct row by using the `WHERE` clause with `OBJECTROWID =` or `OBJECTROWID like`.

[image]

[image]

`SELECT * FROM LDOCLINK WHERE OBJECTROWID like '%';`

gives all the rows (obviously) but I want the row where `OBJECTROWID` equals `<3d98f71f 3cd9415b a978c010 b1cef941>`.  I have tried the following and none of them work:

`SELECT * FROM LDOCLINK WHERE OBJECTROWID = 'X''3d98f71f3cd9415ba978c010b1cef941'` no error - I thought that I was escaping the single quote that appears after the X but this didn't work

`SELECT * FROM LDOCLINK WHERE OBJECTROWID like '%<3d98f71f 3cd9415b a978c010 b1cef941>%'`

I cannot even get a match for two adjacent characters such as the initial `3D`:

`SELECT * FROM LDOCLINK WHERE OBJECTROWID like '%3d%'` no error reported but it doesn't return anything.

`SELECT * FROM LDOCLINK WHERE OBJECTROWID like '%d%'` This is the strangest result as it returns ONLY the two rows that DON'T include my `<3d98f71f 3cd9415b a978c010 b1cef941>`, seemingly arbitrarily.

`SELECT * FROM LDOCLINK WHERE OBJECTTYPE = '0'` returns these same rows, just to illustrate that the interface works (SQLite Manager).

I also checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039461/how-to-display-blob-value-using-xabc-binary-string-literal-syntax) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815587/using-guid-in-sqlite-select-where-guid-is-stored-in-the-sqlite-db-as-binaries?lq=1) one but I still could not get the correct query.

Please help me to return the correct row (actually two rows in this case - the first and third).

EDIT:

The code to write to database involves many classes.  The method shown below is I think the main part of serialisation (case 8).

```
-(void)serializeValue:(NSObject*)value ToBuffer:(NSMutableData*)buffer
{
switch (self.propertyTypeID) {
    case 0:
    {
        SInt32 length = 0;
        if ( (NSString*)value )
        {
            /*
            NSData* data = [((NSString*)value) dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
            // first 2 bytes are unicode prefix
            length = data.length - 2;
            [buffer appendBytes:&length length:sizeof(SInt32)];
            if ( length > 0 )
                [buffer appendBytes:([data bytes]+2) length:length];
            */
            NSData* data = [((NSString*)value) dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            length = data.length;
            [buffer appendBytes:&length length:sizeof(SInt32)];
            if ( length > 0 )
                [buffer appendBytes:([data bytes]) length:length];
        }
        else
            [buffer appendBytes:&length length:sizeof(SInt32)];
    }
        break;
        //depends on the realisation of DB serialisation
    case 1:
    {
        Byte b = 0;
        if ( (NSNumber*)value )
            b = [(NSNumber*)value boolValue] ? 1 : 0;
        [buffer appendBytes:&b length:1];
    }
        break;
//........
    case 8:
    {
        int length = 16;
        [buffer appendBytes:[(NSData*)value bytes] length:length];
    }
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
}
```

Comment: Post the code used to write those values to the database. This will make it much easier to explain how to reverse the process.

Comment: The schema might help: `select * from sqlite_master where name='LDOCLINK' and type='table';`

Comment: @rmaddy.  Thanks.  I posted some, I hope it will help.

Comment: @TomKerr.  Thanks.  This is the result:  `table,"LDOCLINK","LDOCLINK","20","CREATE TABLE LDOCLINK (OBJECTTYPE TEXT,OBJECTROWID GUID,DOCROWID GUID,ROWVERSION BIGINT,ROWID GUID PRIMARY KEY)"`

Comment: possible related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815587/using-guid-in-sqlite-select-where-guid-is-stored-in-the-sqlite-db-as-binaries

Comment: @TomKerr.  Yes, I read that post and tied something but it didn't work first time round BUT, now, `SELECT * FROM LDOCLINK WHERE OBJECTROWID = X'3d98f71f3cd9415ba978c010b1cef941';` works.  Fantastic.  Cheers

Comment: The syntax he used wasn't exactly right.  He suggested the form:  `SELECT * FROM LDOCLINK
WHERE OBJECTROWID.Id = X'a8828ddfef224d36935a1c66ae86ebb3';` but I actually had to drop the `.Id` part (minor gripe).  I'll answer my own question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

So, as pointed out by Tom Kerr, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815587/using-guid-in-sqlite-select-where-guid-is-stored-in-the-sqlite-db-as-binaries) post answered my question.  Almost.  The syntax wasn't exactly right. The form: `SELECT * FROM LDOCLINK WHERE OBJECTROWID.Id = X'a8828ddfef224d36935a1c66ae86ebb3';` was suggested but I actually had to drop the `.Id` part.

Making:

`SELECT * FROM LDOCLINK WHERE OBJECTROWID = X'3d98f71f3cd9415ba978c010b1cef941';`

Comment: This is a [BLOB literal](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#litvalue). If you were using parameters, you could use a 16-byte array with [sqlite3_bind_blob](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html).

Comment: @CL. Thanks, I have it done now using `SELECT * FROM LDOCLINK WHERE OBJECTROWID = ?` and a method in my project to which I pass an array of `OBJECTROWID`'s that I am interested in.