# SQLite Select Where id in GUID

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, xamarin

So I am trying to select all values from a table where `Id in (value,value1,value2)`

Where `value` is a type `Guid`

using this answer: [Using guid in sqlite select where guid is stored in the sqlite db as binaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815587/using-guid-in-sqlite-select-where-guid-is-stored-in-the-sqlite-db-as-binaries)

I have created this Sql statement:

```
Select *
from [Imaging.ImageTag]
where ImageId in (X'b06783c2-da62-4292-8bdc-f7915c00b2db',
                  X'9bc10d55-661b-4530-b224-3fe32651cb74',
                  X'0404c0c1-65a0-4913-9e36-fd9d3e129783',
                  X'cd41ac25-9b75-4d14-bd6b-38e56013020a',
                  X'122014a5-f8bd-4c0b-8c95-b9eec4b60e7e',
                  X'fa4bad5d-42b2-40fa-bf78-4942f29f6355',
                  X'3938b974-d174-4492-9d3b-68733bef9a14',
                  X'b8ac27c4-125f-4fa9-bc91-c6c7fb83c33c',
                  X'0e10bd73-4254-4614-a112-031ce0a3d526',
                  X'd2979e7c-1cb0-40cb-9898-c57d2f4a083a',
                  X'04251d49-9cd8-40d8-9c43-a17a325ddd4b',
                  X'44e56e78-94ce-4308-815d-7d95acae6904',
                  X'481c95d1-52f7-4331-a0f0-a2754dba87f5'
                 )
```

But I get the error:

> unrecognized token: "X'b06783c2-da62-4292-8bdc-f7915c00b2db'"

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `-` symbols? ie: `X'b06783c2da6242928bdcf7915c00b2db'`

Comment: @Igor I thought that may have been it, but I tested it and it returned 0 rows. (it didn't throw an exception though) but doesn't look like that worked either

Comment: If it returned 0 rows and no errors were produced then that is the correct syntax but there are/were just no matches from your list.

Comment: I know there are rows there for those guids. I will keep banging my head against it and let you know if I find anything

Comment: You have to know in what format the values are actually stored. What is the output of `SELECT typeof(ImageId), max(ImageId) FROM ImageTag`?

Comment: @CL it returns `blob`

Comment: And what is the output of `SELECT quote(max(ImageId)) FROM ImageTag`?

Comment: @CL - A load of gibberish characters - `��H{��F@����M�b�`

Comment: must not work because my columns are stored as blobs, therefore I need to convert my guid to a Hexidecimal string that represents the byte array

Comment: The `quote()` function would not output gibberish. Did you actually use it?

Comment: @CL you are right, my bad.. It outputs - `X'FFFC487BA3E4464081BB9D874DDC6299'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I figured it out.

There is no such thing as a `Guid` in Sqlite so it is stored as a `blob` this means when you are trying to query for a given `Guid` you need to convert your guid to a `Hexidecimal string` representation of the `Guid` as a `Byte array`

To do this in `C#` I have the code:

```
query = string.Format("Select * from [TableName] where ImageId in (x'{0}')", string.Join("',x'", ids.Select(x => SqliteDatabaseExtensions.ByteArrayToString(x.ToByteArray())));
```

where `ids`  is a `List<Guid>`

The important bit in this is:

```
SqliteDatabaseExtensions.ByteArrayToString(new Guid(x.ToString()).ToByteArray())
```

Where the static method is:

```
private static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
{
    StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
    foreach (byte b in ba)
        hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
    return hex.ToString();
}
```

Comment: When you have a byte array, you can use it directly as a blob parameter.

Comment: anyone who is still struggling, remember its X not x.