# how to retrieve the image from sqlite in string form and show in list view in android

Tags: android, sqlite

in my project, I fetched data from server through json parsor and store in sqlite database. In the database, image is store as bytearray. When we fetch data from database in cursor we find that all text are shown in text view correctly but image is not shown and error is unable to convert blob to string.

Comment: do not store images in database. Put them on SD card (or internal storage) and keep reference to it in DB only.

Comment: thanks for suggestion but i try but can not getting....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well like WebnetMobile.com said, what would you save it on the database ? its faster to store it in a directory and manage it from there, BUT if you really need it on the database, have you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039461/how-to-display-blob-value-using-xabc-binary-string-literal-syntax) ?

i hope this can help you.