# Opposite of HEX() in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, hex

I have this simple query that returns a bunch of guids as hexadecimal strings:

```
SELECT HEX(guid) FROM table;
```

One of them is for instance `43F4124307108902B7A919F4D4D0770D`. Then imagine I want to get the record with this guid, so I write a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE guid = '43F4124307108902B7A919F4D4D0770D';
```

Of course, this will not work, since the string is directly interpreted as a blob and not converted to it's hex value. I looked [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html), but couldn't find anything that looks like a method that takes a hexadecimal string and converts it to a blob.

Comment: why don't you use `SELECT * FROM table WHERE guid = 'HEX(43F4124307108902B7A919F4D4D0770D)'`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

While writing the question I found the answer. I simply had to add an X before the string. Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE guid = X'43F4124307108902B7A919F4D4D0770D';
```

I figured I should post the question anyway, since non of the "Similar Questions" answers this. What I was looking for was not a function, but a literal and when I realized this I quickly found the answer [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039461/how-to-display-blob-value-using-xabc-binary-string-literal-syntax answered your question indirectly.

Answer (score 1):

In the upcoming version it's supported:

SQLite version 3.41.0 2023-02-08 12:47:37

Enter ".help" for usage hints.

Connected to a transient in-memory database.

Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.

sqlite> select unhex('41')
...> ;

A

sqlite> select hex('a')
...> ;

61

sqlite> .q