# Android: how to query SQLiteDatabase with non-string selection args?

Tags: android, sql, select, sqlite

Is there a straightforward way to query an `SQLiteDatabase` with selection args that are not `String` types?

Particularly: if the arg is a `byte[]` type?

The closest thing I can find is `SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement()`, which returns an `SQLiteStatement` you can call `bindBlob` etc. on. Unfortunately `SQLiteStatement` isn't good for querying because it doesn't return a cursor.

`SQLiteCursor` looks promising but I can't figure out how to use it.

Comment: Querying based on a blob sounds horribly inefficient. Are you sure this is the only way to write your query?

Comment: Yeah. It's not necessarily a large blob.

Comment: Is there a way to even *express* a query that has a BLOB in its WHERE clause? Forget Android for the moment: how would you do this in ordinary SQL?

Comment: Good question. Could a byte _literal_ somehow be expressed in an sql statement? While I can't verify right now, it seems that the SQLite C api does allow querying via prepared statements, which you can bind blobs to via sqlite3_bind_blob. [link](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html)

Comment: You'll have to implement your own `SQLiteCursorDriver` if you want to make use of the `bindBlob()` method.

Comment: Answering previous comments: searching by an indexed `TEXT` column is not horribly inefficient, and `BLOB`s are even simpler — no charset, no unicode decomposition, no case sensitivity, etc — so searching by such a column is OK. And SQL supports [blob literals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1039553/3050249).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a design bug in the Android database API.

`query` and `rawQuery` accept only string parameters.
`execSQL` accepts any `Object` parameters, but does not return results.
`SQLiteStatement` accepts parameters of any type, but allows only queries that return a single value.

What you can do is to ignore parameters, and format the blobs as [blob literals](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#litvalue) by hand:

```java
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT a FROM b WHERE c = x'112233'", null);
```

Answer (score 2):

also you may try

```
Cursor cs = db.rawQueryWithFactory(new CursorFactory() {
            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public Cursor newCursor(SQLiteDatabase db, SQLiteCursorDriver masterQuery,
                    String editTable, SQLiteQuery query) {

                // bind it here!...
                query.bindBlob(1, mac);



                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
                    return new SQLiteCursor(db, masterQuery, editTable, query);
                } else {
                    return new SQLiteCursor(masterQuery, editTable, query);
                }
            }
        }, query, null, DB_TABLE);
```

Comment: Nice solution. But sending null in the parameters at last line will through an exception. You have to send parameters as Array<String>