# How to *always* display blob value using x'abc' binary string literal syntax?

Tags: sqlite, blob, literals, quoting

Very similar to [How to display blob value using x'abc' binary string literal syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039461/):

How can I have the `sqlite3` shell display always display blob columns using the hex notation, as per e.g. `quote(blob_column_name)`, without explicitly using `quote`, and in `select *` queries (and other contexts where `blob_column_name` isn't mentioned explicitly)?

(I suspect the answer is "you can't", but I'm hoping to be pleasantly surprised.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two output modes that use SQL syntax (not only for blobs but for all values):

```
sqlite> .mode quote
sqlite> SELECT 1, x'123ABC', 'hello', null;
1,X'123abc','hello',NULL
sqlite> .mode insert
sqlite> SELECT 1, x'123ABC', 'hello', null;
INSERT INTO "table" VALUES(1,X'123abc','hello',NULL);
```

Comment: Good catch. `.mode quote` was added for sqlite `3.15.1`; I've been using `3.11.0`, which explains why I didn't see the option!

Unfortunately, there's no way AFAICT to have both `quote` and `columns` modes, but I'll learn to live with it. :-)